# Separating nested for loops in list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Starting from this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                    'x': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
                    'y': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]})
```

it's possible to simplify these nested for loops:

```
for t, df in df2.groupby('t'):
    print("t:", t)
    for d in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
        print({'x': d['x'], 'y': d['y']})
```

by separating the inner loop into a function:

```
def handle(df):
    for d in df.to_dict(orient='records'):    
        print({'x': d['x'], 'y': d['y']})

for t, df in df2.groupby('t'):
    print("t:", t)
    handle(df)
```

How might I similarly separate a nested list comprehension :

```
mydict = {
    t: [{'x': d['x'], 'y': d['y']} for d in df.to_dict(orient='records')]
       for t, df in df2.groupby(['t'])
}
```

into two separate loops?

I'm asking the question with just two levels of nesting, yet with just two nested loops the need is hardly critical. The motivations are:

- By the time there are a few levels, the code becomes tough to read.
- Developing and testing smaller blocks guards against (present and future) mistakes at more than the outer level.

Comment: Why can't you use the same `handle` function? `{t: handle(df) for t,df in df2.groupby(['t'])}`. Obviously right now your `handle` functions is `print`ing but you simply have to return that list instead...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta You suggest that there should be a CR/LF between `{` and `t` in `mydict = {t:`. Does PEP-8 have an opinion on this issue? I cannot determine which of the two is more readable, but I'll gladly be convinced with your point of view for changing the indentation.

Comment: @Vrokipal,  as i see your code is working and you are looking for a better and  elegant way to do this, i believe you should post it on code review ! You will get it reviewed and will get better possible answer.